# SQL Server 2008R2 Cannot Connect to Local on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Box was corrupt and was cleaned up and operational. Now, SQL Server will not connect to my db.  I checked services and found that `mssqlserver`, SQL Server agents won't start. Gives error

> Cannot connect to local server

They are set to automatically start, but manually starting gives the same error.

Comment: What did you do to `"Clean"` your box ?

Comment: Assuming the required services are running, (sqlservr.exe) and the SQL instance is named the same, I'd reinstall SQL Server and attach the database to the new instance.

Comment: Check the SQL Server Error Log for problems with the instance.  It'll be somewhere like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG`

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned his box with this recipe that I use successfully on dozens of computers. All other software is running fine. His box also had a failing disk so I xxcloned (XXClone.com) his disk to a fresh new disk. I believe the cleaning is an unrelated issue, but whatever it takes to fix it we are happy to try. I know many people with this SQL Server issue, and over the years have fixed it a few ways, but I am tight on time, so I suggested he get help here.

THOROUGH BADDY CLEAN. Clean a Windows Machine without Formatting it or losing Data

STEP 1

If Ransomware or some baddy is taking over our MBR or Partition so you cannot escape it, and cannot run safe mode, the ICE Ransomware being one of many examples.....

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-ice-cyber-crime-center-ransomware

use a empty USB stick and HitManPro (the free version will remove)

http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro/

STEP 2

Reboot in Safe mode with networking by rebooting and holding down F8 key. None of this will permanently fix your computer unless you are in SAFE MODE w/ NETWORKING

1. Download RKill and run it
2. Download ComboFix from BleepingComputer.org and run it
3. Download SmitFraudFix and run it
4. Download AntiMalwareBytes to catch everything those did not

I can clean any machine no matter how badly infected with these tools in safe mode. Will keep recurring if attempted in Normal Mode. Safe mode is the key.